# Localisation using l10ns

Tags: javascript, html, localization, internationalization

Im trying to implement localisation in javascript.
Tried using [L10ns](http://l10ns.org). After trying the steps, I could not generate any resource file.

Let me understand that using this library can I generate language resource file and how do i used it in my html file.

Also please suggest some other better javascript libraries which i can use it for localisations

Answer (score 0):

The workflow is quite easy. Let say, that you want to write a hello world application:

You first need to add the translation to your html file, so you place the following script under your `<head>` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/output/all.js"></script>
```

After that you just need require the right language:

```
var l = requireLocalizations('en-US');
console.log(l('NEW_KEY'));
```

The workflow is as followed:

1. You write your `l('NEW_KEY')` function calls to get a localized string. You write these calls before you generate them.
2. After you have written some localization string calls. You would need to update so that `L10ns` would know that you have added som new localization keys, which in this case is `'NEW_KEY'`. You do that with `l10ns update`. L10ns will store the new key in some kind of storage.
3. Now you want to translate the new string for `NEW_KEY`. You can do that in two ways. One way is with the a web interface with `l10ns interface`. The other way, is with the command line. `l10ns set @1 "hello world"`. The `@1` is a reference to the latest added localization key. `@2` is the next latest etc.
4. Now, it is time to generate the code for the new localization key. You do that with `l10ns compile`.

After these steps it will output a `hello world` string.

Comment: Please disclose any [affiliations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and do not use the site as a way to promote your site through posting. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).